# The problem with the transfer of the website to symfony

Tags: symfony, redirect

After the transfer of the site to a new hosting, there is a problem: the site produces an event redirect to the old hosting.  Currently set up nginx on something that would have sent data to pure servers but it produces still a redirect. The redirect itself is made starting from the app file.php to HttpKernel.php in handler (......) there is a call to events, $this->dispatcher - >dispatch(.................) which forms a redirect and does not let on, if you remove this element, then the page is formed only without data from the database and there is an error 404 page not found. When the page loads, a kernel event is generated.request and security.authentication.success and with such parameters it produces a redirect.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from some guidance on how to ask a good question and provide a minimal example. At the moment I'm not sure what you are asking about in terms of coding or programming. If your website is broken, contact the support of your hosting provider.

Answer (score -1):

Check for kernel request events. You may have a hardcode somewhere. I dont know much about your symfony version, but you can debug events with `php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.exception`. After you do this post code here we might be able to help. AND YES question is formed very poorly.